# elasticsearch term aggregation with filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I got entities like this in `foo` index:

```
{ids: ["aa", "bb"]}
{ids: ["aa", "cc"]}
{ids: ["ee"]}
{ids: ["ff" , "cc"]}
```

Basically I want to know are there documents for ids `aa` and `ee`.
I tried to do it with terms aggregation

```
{
    "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
             {
                  "terms": {
                    "ids": [
                      "aa", "ee"
                    ],
                    "boost": 1
                 }
              }
           ],
           "adjust_pure_negative": true,
           "boost": 1
         }
      },
  "aggregations": {
    "byid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ids",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the problem here that in response I got aggregation also with other `ids` that selected entities have, and there are a lot of them in real case, so the aggregation for `ids` that I interested in could not come in response and I will think that there is no items for them (but actually there are, but not in response because of term size limit)

I could do it for every `id` separately without aggs just get a `count`, but there are a lot of them and it will be very expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on chat, found that no of documents containing the ids are not required, hence aggregation is not required, now whether a particular id is present in the search result or not is the main issue.

there are a couple of approaches:

1. Use [multi_search with a single id in each sub-request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)
2. Use a single search request with all the ids, but do post-processing using a script or [source_filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html) and search id in the response.

Comment: I need to know existence for each id separately.

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев pls see my updated answer, I didn't get what do you mean by existance of each id ?? would be great if you can provide ur expected output

Comment: Read till the end please, there are a lot of ids in real case, and size limit of terms aggreagation could throw away ids I am interested in.
For example if I am interested in `aa` and `zz` ids. from query response I should understand that there are some docs for `aa` but no docs for `zz` and from simple search I could not understand that

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев, you can give size attribute in aggregation, so that it returns you all the results but yes, there is performance penality

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев Also using the https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html source filtering, you can know which id, your search results conatins

Comment: I can't give size attribute because at first I need to know how much unique ids there, but  more important there are near 23m of them, so yes, there is performance penalty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224246/discussion-between-elasticsearch-ninja-and--).